# Chrome Remote Desktop connection abort on Kubuntu 20.04, Launch the default XSession

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma, chrome-remote-desktop

I have used Chrome Remote Desktop for a while and was really happy with it. After a power outage at the remote machine I could not connect to it any more.

The remote machines appear in the Google Remote Desktop overview. After I click on it, I have enter the PIN. Then I have to select the session to launch. There are three options:

- Launch the default XSession
- Plasma by KDE
- Use this session to run Xfce as your desktop environment

If I select the XSession, I get a black screen and after a while the overview window appears with the message, that the session was ended. The Plasma by KDE selection seems to crash the whole plasma user interface, as it gets completely frozen after selecting the second option. The third option establishes a remote connection, but the user interface is different to the one I know from Kubuntu and does not seem to work without limitations for the programs I use.

I assume that something is wrong with the KDE wallet, as Chrome Remote Desktop does not seem to be connected to it any more.

Are there any hints how to get back to a my remote connection?

Comment: Hi @Hendrik, did you manage to solve the issue? I am having a similar issue and do not know what to try. Thanks

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. I'm also still open for any useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

This problem most likely is caused by an active session on the host. Try to kill the active session to make sure this is the problem. SSH into the host and run the following:

```
qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0
```

Launch using Plasma by KDE, and see if it's working.

---

Follow the instructions on using the same session:

- https://superuser.com/a/850359/1318949
- https://medium.com/@vsimon/how-to-install-chrome-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-52d99980d83e
- https://gist.github.com/nightuser/2ec1b91a66ec33ef0a0a67b6c570eb40